# Azure Data Factory: How to set variable after for each successfully run?

Tags: azure-data-factory, kql

I Am working one Azure copy data pipeline where I want to do validation of data.
: Input records should be matched with Output records.

. pipeline is copy, incremental data. So for this I have following set variable .

1:start time=>set current UTC time for calculating pipeline start time.

```
(Utcnow())
```

2: End time=>for set pipeline end time after run.

```
(Utcnow())
```

3:Total Time=>then I subtract start time from end time for calculating the exact time.

```
(@string(div(sub(ticks(Utcnow()),ticks(variables('Start'))),600000000))
)
```

4:Then I check total inserted records with Kusto table.(ago (50m) is pipeline calculated Total time )

Kusto query:

5:Output_LK=> sample |where ingestion_time()>ago(50m)|summarize rowcount=count()|project rowcount | take 1

6:Get Request:

```
Sample1
|summarize rowcount=count()
|project rowcount
```

Pipeline Query: `@if(equals(activity('Output_LK').output.firstrow.rowcount,activity('Get Request').output.firstrow.rowcount),concat('Total Number Of input RECORDS is  ',activity('Get Request').output.firstrow.rowcount,'Total Number of output records is ',activity('Output_LK').output.firstrow.rowcount),concat('Total Number Of input RECORDS is  ',activity('Get Request').output.firstrow.rowcount,'Total Number of output records is ',activity('Output_LK').output.firstrow.rowcount))`

I get the result but This 3rd step executed for for loop completion.

so My result is not exact as expected.

Comment: What exactly is the discrepancy you are seeing?
Have you checked failures on your cluster?
What is your data format?
How long does a typical cycle take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ago() function will use a different time range each time you execute the query according to the execution time, what can result with different results.
You can query by the start time and duration to get the exact time range.

sample
|where ingestion_time() between(startTime ..50m)
|summarize rowcount=count()
|project rowcount
| take 1